# Jest simulate click on one instance of a component that may be rendered several times

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to test that my onClick function is called correctly when a button is clicked. However, there are many buttons in my frontend code that should all call the same function.

Currently my test looks like this:

```
function render(args, renderer = shallow) {
    const component = renderer(<MyComponent {...args} />);

    return {
      component,
      buttons: () => component.find(".button"),
    };
  }


  beforeEach(() => {
    myProps = {
      myFunction: jest.fn(),
    };
  });

  it("Should call myFunction when button is clicked", () => {
    const { buttons } = render(myProps);
    buttons().simulate("click");

    expect(myProps.myFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
  });
```

So in this instance `buttons()` is returning several nodes, as it's finding multiple buttons. However when I call `simulate("click")` it needs to be on one button only. So first I tried just selecting the first from a list:

```
buttons()[0].simulate("click");
```

But unfortunately it seems that that returns undefined, rather than the first node as I hoped.

How do I specify only one of these buttons when they don't have any unique class identifier?

Comment: Is this issue fixed ?

Comment: @UKS Yes I was able to fix it with what I found in the documentation below

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around in the documentation I found `.first()` which can be used in this situation instead of `[0]` but achieves the same result.

```
buttons().first().simulate("click");
```

There's also `.last()` and `.at(index)` which are all useful in situations like this.

https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/first.html